# How to fix old data after update spring batch to 4.2.4

Tags: spring-batch

When I try deserialize data I got deserialize error. I have serialized data with XStream serializer in short_context(batch_job_execution_context) and I need to update spring batch to 4.2.4 which uses Jackson serializer. Can I change the data to fix it?

Comment: What is the current Spring Batch version? v3 used Xstream while v4 uses Jackson, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/whatsnew.html#whatsNewSerialization.

Comment: Yep current Spring Batch v3, but I need to save already existing data and use Jackson, can I do it or need to remove old jobs serialized with XStream?

Comment: You can switch to Jackson, but you should not try to restart failed job executions that were serialized with Xstream.